# Gaussian integers modulo $prime$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I want to prove that $\phi :\mathbb Z_{p^k}[i] \mapsto\mathbb Z_p[i] $ as $\phi : a+bi\bmod p^k \mapsto a+bi\bmod p$ is a surjective ring homomorphisim.

I have already proven that its homomorphism. But how can I prove that it is surjective?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't that trivial? I mean, you'd have to prove that

$$\;F:\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;,\;\;F(a):=a\pmod p\;$$

is surjective...but **any** $\;w\in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$ is *already* an element in $\;\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z\;$ ...

Comment: okay thanks. Actually I was thinking that  $Z_p[i]$ is a subset of $Z_{p^k}$ so the mapping is surjective but its too simple. So I thought my assumption is wrong. By the way thank you.

Comment: @Isiah Any time. Sometimes things are so abstract that we can miss the obvious. Happens to me all the time...:)